# Error de sintaxis SQL pero el query esta correcto

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy tratando de hacer un update a la tabla usuarios, especificamente a las columnas usuario, email, password pero el update es a un id especifico, es query lo copie literalmente como lo genera phpmyadmin pues de ahi jalo todos mis inserts y deletes. Queda de esta forma:

```
 public function update(){

    $sql = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `usuario`='{$this->usuario}',`email`='{$this->email}',`password`='{$this->password}' WHERE `id` = '{$this->id}'";
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump(mysqli_error($this->db));
    die();
    $save = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = false;

    if ($save) {
        $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

En el codigo para ver que podria estaba mal pues el mysqli no me dabda bien donde estaba el error, imprimi la sentencia sql, que queda asi:

```
string(153) "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `usuario`='vader',`email`='vader@l.com',`password`='$2y$04$jwwxuh5oEoGb9AAnOqU2He9.kZISscxcg0mTa6Bi4Hpl1kg9FjjPK' WHERE `id` = '10'"
```

y el error que da:

```
string(149) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1"
```

pero cuando prubas esa misma sentencia en phpmyadmin la da sin problemas, si alguien puede ayudarme le estaria muy agradecido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En VScode el parametro password me sale como palabra reservada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la salida en el navegador de los var_dump
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con un vardump a save
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El origen del 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los dos strings son lo de var_dump..!

Comment: Quítales las: **`**

Comment: ya le quite las `, y ya esta lo que me regresan los var_dump

Comment: El primer error que noto es que en tu impresión sale un **1**, ahora, probablemente el error se deba a qué estas teniendo **'** demás. ¿Dónde ejecutas tu php? ¿Cómo es el formulario? @HeyL1nk

Comment: ahh el uno es porque para mandar a llamar update entro a un metodo, y para ver si si entraba pues le puse que imprimiera un 1. Lo ejecuto en Apache, o si te refieres al formulario es uno para modificar el perfil, los datos del formulario abren mi url_base, el controlador de este y la accion de update, y este llama al modelo donde esta la funcion que puse, pero, los datos llegan

Comment: Ok, si el save te muestra bool(true), es que es correcto. El error que estás mostrando debe ser de otra consulta anterior.

Comment: Puedes hacer el mismo procedimento para consultas anteriores que estes haciendo ?? Luego de la ejecucion de la consulta, manda un var_dump() de la consulta, más la ejecucion de la query. Y le metes la cadena `var_dump(mysqli_error($this->db));` a ver cuando aparece el error.

Comment: A diferencia de MySQL, que hace conversión automática, a MariaDB no le gusta recibir valores numéricos encerrados entre comillas. Seguramente hay una opción para configurar la conversión, pero lo desconozco, por lo que solo puedo sugerir que cambies tu consulta a: `"UPDATE \`usuarios\` SET \`usuario\`='vader',`email`='vader@l.com',\`password\`='$2y$04$jwwxuh5oEoGb9AAnOqU2He9.kZISscxcg0mTa6Bi4Hpl1kg9FjjPK' WHERE \`id\` = 10"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En definitiva pienso, que el error que estás mostrando corresponde a otra sentencia que se ejecuta anteriormente. Porque:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `usuario`='{$this->usuario}',`email`='{$this->email}',`password`='{$this->password}' WHERE `id` = '{$this->id}'";
var_dump(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

Actualmente, estas 2 líneas de código, NO ESTAN RELACIONADAS.
Acabas de declarar una variable, no has realizado la consulta, es decir, no la has ejecutado.

Al pedirte que realices un `var_dump($save)` este está retornándote -> `bool(true)`. Lo que significa que la consulta UPDATE, es correcta, y se ejecutó correctamente. Por lo que si `$save` es true, significa que `$result` será true igualmente.
Tal y como lo estás haciendo en PhpMyAdmin.

Mi recomendación, es realizar una revisión de otras consultas que estés ejecutando. Y así poder encontrar el problema.

---

Dado que en la salida, está mostrando un 1, deberías comenzar a revisar las consultas realizadas posterior a ese 1.